# doctrine relation on integer field returns string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

My schema.yml

```
Organisation:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name: { type: string(100), notnull: true, unique: true }
    parent_organisation_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: false }

  relations:
    ParentOrganisation: { class: Organisation, local: parent_organisation_id, foreignAlias: ChildOrganisations }
```

Some organisations have the integer value 0 stored and there is no such organisation_id. To my surprise when I run this code

```
class organisationActions extends autoOrganisationActions{

    public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request){

        $this->organisation = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
        $p = $this->organisation->getParentOrganisationId();
        var_dump($p);
```

The result is string(1) "0"

Why does this not return an integer, so I can compare === 0

Comment: Hi @jdog, which environment and stack do you use? PHP Version, sf version (1.4 i suppose...), propel or doctrine? mysql or postgres? So i can replicate your problem....

Comment: Hi @jdog, what about my answer?

Comment: ID = 0 on a DB is a madness for this exact reason: casting. Good luck with that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do some test and I see that every value of an entity are returned via magic call that the parent class of every Entity model `sfDoctrineRecord` do in the `_call` method. So the return type of the `call_user_func_array` seem don't distinct against string or int etc. The same behaviour we have on every field of every entity so implemented, the **id** field also.

So, as ***workaround***, you can implement your custom getter for check if the records is null or is the first (id=0) for compare operation as follow:

```
class Organisation extends BaseOrganisation
{

        public function getParentIdAsIntegerOrNullOtherwise()
        {
            $an_id = $this->getParentOrganisationId();

            if (! is_null($an_id))
            {
                return intval($an_id);
            }

            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

In the controller:

```
    $p = $this->organisation->getParentIdAsIntegerOrNullOtherwise();

    var_dump($p);
```

It will dump

```
NULL
```

if is not linked to any parent node

and will dump

```
int(0)
```

if this is linked to the element with id = 0

Hope this help

Let me know what you think about it

Comment: Hi @matteo, sorry for the delay in getting back to this. I see my mistake is that the result is actually null, which is cast to string, because of the var_dump()? in any case your answer helped me solve the problem.